# Prevent rollup from renaming Promise to Promise$1

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

**Update:** Turned out that this is not a problem with Babel, but with Rollup, which is run before. Thanks for your help anyway and sorry for the noise.

I use [rollup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup) to bundle a number of modules including a Promise polyfill (deliberately overwriting the global Promise). However, rollup recognizes `Promise` as a global name and transforms

```
export default function Promise(fn) { ... }
...
global.Promise = Promise;
```

to

```
function Promise$1(fn) { ... }
...
global.Promise = Promise$1;
```

The resulting code works, but I would like the following assertion to hold true:

```
expect(Promise.name).to.equal('Promise');
```

Is there any way to tell rollup to leave the constructor name intact?

Comment: What babel plugins are you using? What specifically is Babel changing in your output file?

Comment: Don't test for names. They're insignificant.

Comment: Not sure about the update. Did you solve the problem? Are you now asking how to tell Rollup to leave the name alone? If you found a solution, please [post it as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), if not, please [edit] to clarify your setup and what you are looking for; or if you moved on just delete the question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've now updated the question. I hesitated to change the topic as I wasn't sure if that's good practice...

Comment: @Bergi That's not quite true. Type checks are often based on `constructor.name` in JS. The name is also taken into account by the formatter used in the Node.js console ([example](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/util.js#L473)).

Comment: @ralfstx Type checks based on `.constructor.name` should not be used precisely for this reason. Names get mangled by transpilers, bundlers and minifiers. Older browsers don't implement them at all. Use `instanceof`, `typeof` or shape detection (existence and type of properties) instead. Debugging and logging is a different topic, that's usually done in known environments and with the original source.

Comment: @Bergi The thing is that I'm working on [such an environment](https://github.com/eclipsesource/tabris-js) that implements stuff like logging, and that's why I have this issue ;-) Apart from that, `constructor` and `constructor.name` are part of the ES 2015 spec, so I can't quite follow your advice to generally avoid them.

Comment: @ralfstx `name` might be part of ES6, but that doesn't mean it's web-compatible. IE doesn't support it at all, so I recommend to avoid it there. In your environment, it seems to be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [rollup-plugin-inject](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-inject) and configuring it to add `import Promise from 'your-promise-polyfill'` to any files that reference `Promise`. That way, Rollup won't think that it needs to rename the function declared in the polyfill to avoid clashing with the global, because it won't be aware that there *is* a global that it's clashing with.

```js
// rollup.config.js
import inject from 'rollup-plugin-inject';

export default {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    inject({
      Promise: 'your-promise-polyfill'
    })
  ]
};
```