# How to prevent babel from renaming global to global$1

Tags: javascript, babeljs, rollup

here a similar question [Prevent rollup from renaming Promise to Promise$1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549689/prevent-rollup-from-renaming-promise-to-promise1)
, but my problem is still unresolved.

I use Rollup and babel to bundle a number of modules including a variable `global`.

when i didn't use `Babel Plugins`, it outputs `global`, that's what i need

However, when i use `Babel Plugins`, it outputs `global$1`

How to prevent the renaming?

here go code

- in `.babelrc` I use some plugins to transform my code

```js
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "modules": false
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [               // I use some plugins to transform my code
    "external-helpers",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-object-assign"
  ]
}
```

- in my `rollup.config.js`: I try to use `rollup-plugin-inject` which is used to resolve the problem [Prevent rollup from renaming Promise to Promise$1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549689/prevent-rollup-from-renaming-promise-to-promise1)
  , but it didn't work, so i think that the renaming was caused by Bable Plugin

```js
{
    plugins: [
      paths,
      resolve({
        jsnext: true,
        main: true
      }),
      commonjs({
        include: 'node_modules/**'
      }),
      inject({                 // use `rollup-plugin-inject`
        global: './global.js'
      }),
      babel({
        exclude: 'node_modules/**'
      })
    ]
  }
}
```

- `global.js`: export variable 'global'

```js
var global = this
export default global
```

- `index.js`: import variable 'global'

```js
import global from './global'

console.log('index.js:', global);
```

and it transforms to the code :

```js
'use strict';

var global = this;

console.log('index.js:', global);
```

**However**, when i add the code like this:

- `index.js`: add `Object.assign` which will be transformed by Babel Plugin

```js
'use strict';

var global = this;

let foo = Object.assign({}, { bar: 5 })  // Here ~
```

and then, after the transform, it turn out:

```js
'use strict';

var global$1 = this;             // the global is renamed to global$1

var _extends = Object.assign || ...

var c = _extends({}, { p: 5 });
```

As you see, the variable `global` was renamed to `global$1`

Is there some idea to prevent the renaming ??

Comment: you can use window.global

Comment: @deathangel908 This code isn't running in the browser or Node，so that there isn't 'window' or 'global'. I want to set this variable 'global' to replace ' this ', because the environment of running will be injected with some function which are used to communicate with Native, and we can use global to call them. Also a easy way can to do it, don't call it 'global', call it other name, like '_global'. But if want to call 'global', how to resolve it?
(I'm sorry for my poor standard of English )

Comment: `This code isn't running in the browser or Node.` Where is it running? What I'm trying to say you're searching in the wrong direction, you don't need to prevent babel from renaming the variable, you need to find a way to inject your global variable into pieces of your code.

Comment: Yes, you are right, maybe i search in the wrong directioin. I will try more in other direction which can work better. Thank you ~ 

Comment: `This code isn't running in the browser or Node`, that is because I put my js code to running in jsEngine，where I injected some global variable, so that we can get those var from ` this `. And I just want to set the `global` to replace `this`, in this way, we can use like: `global. callNative(...)`.

Comment: Can you pass it as a param to your function?

Comment: Why does it matter if `global` is renamed? Do you have code you didn't include that depends on that name?

Comment: @nathancahil I try to let the `global` be the global variable, so that in other files can use it without `import`, and after rollup generate the bundle, I can still use the variable `global`.  Now I get a way is that, set the Rollup config item: `banner: 'var global = this'`，in this way, this variable will expose and don't be renamed.